# Cannot add ArcGIS service from a Linux based server in ArcMap (admin)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop, installation, linux, arcgis-10.2

I have installed ArcGIS Server 10.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 (with few tricks which I would be happy to share) and got the server up and running to the extent that I can manage the server through the webinterface and even add it in ArcMap for accessing the maps.
My problem is that when I add the server for management, it asks for a hostname and when I enter the same name as it appears on the ArcGIS web interface (where the machines managed by the server is listed), ArcMap complains about not being able to find the machine with the given hostname.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please do share your method for installing AGS on Ubuntu. Perhaps ask a new question "How do I install ArcGIS Server 10.2 on Ubuntu?" and then answer it yourself.

Comment: By following the installation guide (Linux) from ESRI: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-unix/10.2/

Comment: How is following the guide "tricks"?

Comment: OK, so the guide does not tell you how to do the installation on Ubuntu and some steps do not work if you blindly follow, i.e. for some commands, you should do the equivalent things on Ubuntu; e.g. replacing **chkconfig** service management with **update-rc.d** the config file xvfb needs should be borrowed from another platform as well. But all in all, the serve management interface gets up and running on port 6080/6443. As I said, I can add the server in ArcMap on some other machine too. The Problem is that I cannot add it in admin mode.